# Nodejs POST request getting stuck infinite loop - MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

`GET` request is working fine and showing data, I am not getting why `post` request is getting stuck, can someone please help to fix.

```js
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const Contact = require('../models/contactModel');
//@desc Get All Contacts
//@route GET /api/contacts
//@access public
const getContacts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const contacts = await Contact.find();
    res.status(200).json(contacts);
});

//@desc Create New Contact
//@route POST /api/contacts
//@access public
const createContact = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {

    const { name, phone } = req.body;
    if (!name || !phone) {
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("Name and Phone are mandatory!");
    }
    const contact = await Contact.create({
        name,
        email,
        phone,
    });
    res.status(201).json(contact);
});
module.exports = { getContacts, createContact };
```

Mongoose Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const contactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add the contact name'],
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add the contact email address'],
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add the phone number'],
    }
},
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("contacts", contactSchema);
```

`GET` request is working properly, also database is getting connected, but don't know what went wrong, can someone please help to fix it?